# Cache file handle to netCDF files in python

Tags: python, netcdf

Is there a way to cache python file handles? I have a function which takes a netCDF file path as input, opens it, extracts some data from the netCDF file and closes it. It gets called a lot of times, and the overhead of opening the file each time is high.

How can I make it faster by maybe caching the file handle? Perhaps there is a python library to do this

Comment: Can't you keep the file open and then send a file object as a function argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use following python libraries:

- [dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) (required)
- [python-memcached](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-memcached) (optional)

Let's follow the example. You have two files:

```
# save.py - it puts deserialized file handler object to memcached
import dill
import memcache            


mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
file_handler = open('data.txt', 'r')
mc.set("file_handler", dill.dumps(file_handler))
print 'saved!'
```

and

```
# read_from_file.py - it gets deserialized file handler object from memcached, 
#                     then serializes it and read lines from it
import dill
import memcache


mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
file_handler = dill.loads(mc.get("file_handler"))
print file_handler.readlines()
```

Now if you run:

```
python save.py
python read_from_file.py
```

you can get what you want.

**Why it works?**

Because you didn't close the file (`file_handler.close()`), so object still exist in memory (has not been garbage collected, because of [weakref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html)) and you can use it. Even in different process.

**Solution**

```
import dill
import memcache


mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
serialized = mc.get("file_handler")
if serialized:
    file_handler = dill.loads(serialized)
else:
    file_handler = open('data.txt', 'r')
    mc.set("file_handler", dill.dumps(file_handler))
print file_handler.readlines()
```

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

```
filehandle = None
def get_filehandle(filename):
    if filehandle is None or filehandle.closed():
        filehandle = open(filename, "r")
    return filehandle
```

You may want to encapsulate this into a class to prevent other code from messing with the `filehandle` variable.